# Tree view -- inserting at end is slower than beginning, but deletion is faster?

Tags: winapi, treeview

I was just shocked to learn that inserting in a [tree view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759988.aspx) is *much* faster with `TVI_FIRST` than `TVI_LAST`.

By contrast, deletion is slower -- my program exits a lot more slowly when I use it.

Why is this?!

Comment: Interestingly this behavior is called out in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I'm curious how many nodes you have?  Obviously with TVI_LAST is has to traverse all nodes at that level, but that doesn't seem like it would be particularly expensive...

Comment: It's not expensive for reasonable-sized treeviews. The problem occurs when people start creating nodes with 100,000 children.

Comment: @Luke: That part of the documentation didn't use to be there -- it's not in my local version (VS 2008)! Also, there is no mention of *deletions*, which is the really weird part...

Comment: @RaymondChen: *Actually*, I'm only inserting 28,298 nodes, and the difference is still ridiculously visible...

Comment: Oh, _only_ 28,298.  Yeah, that's practically nothing. :)

Comment: @Luke: Lol, the difference is still visible (although not nearly as much) with 7,018 nodes. Which, compared to 100,000, is indeed practically nothing. :P

Comment: I don't know about you, but if I had to use a tree view with thousands of nodes I think I would just kill myself instead.  There are practical limits to what you should do with controls; Windows Explorer (as one example) blows chunks when you try to view a folder that has thousands of files.

Comment: @Luke: FYI, the registry editor opens up thousands of nodes every time you open `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes`. So does Windows Explorer, when you open up `C:\Windows\WinSxS`... and frankly, those are the two main uses of tree views in Windows, AFAIK.

Comment: Just because Microsoft does it doesn't mean it's the way to go.  Unfortunately there is not really a better way, but that doesn't mean the current method doesn't suck.

Comment: Hey, I think you inspired the [latest blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/11/25/10241394.aspx) from Mr. Chen.

Comment: @Luke: Wow, that's amazing. Thanks so much for posting the link! (If you'd like, post it as an answer so I can accept it!)

Comment: @Luke Actually, that article had been in the queue for over a year. The timing is just a coincidence.

Comment: @RaymondChen : Awwwww I thought I was special for a couple hours. :'(

Answer (score 0):

bracket your code with this:

SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETREDRAW, FALSE, 0);

///////

....

SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETREDRAW, TRUE, 0);

It's the redraw that's slow.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer with more details?

Comment: I'm not certain I can.  What would you like to know?  You can easily look up the documentation or other online discussion of WM_SETREDRAW.  Basically, you are telling Windows "I'm going to do more than one thing, so don't bother to redraw after every one."

Comment: I was reviewing your answer. Please add the details to your answer editing it.